# Bluetooth devices make everything lag

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, 22.04

I recently installed ubuntu 22.04 on a new Lenovo Thinkpad T14s Gen 2a.

Whenever I try to use any Bluetooth device with the laptop my computer seems to lag and stutter. It is clearly worst for things like watching Youtube, but to me it seems also non-internet based stuff begins to lag.

I have found a few different solutions that links similar issues to the bandwidth of the Wifi (e.g. [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/ngk6rq/bluetooth_interferes_with_wifi_in_ubuntu_2004/) or [here](https://techvorm.com/fix-wifi-not-working-slows-ubuntu-bluetooth-turned)), but neither seems to solve my issue. Moreover the issue also arises - albeit somewhat less bad - when I am using the 5Ghz bandwith (which I checked by running `iwconfig`).

Even with the lags according to [speedtest.net](https://www.speedtest.net/) my connection is actually quite decent.

As I only ever had Ubuntu installed I do not know if the same issues would arise in windows.

Does anyone know what to do about this? For my productivity it is quite important to use a Bluetooth keyboard, mouse and headphones - so if this issue can't be solved I might have to switch back to Windows after using Ubuntu for some years now.

Hardware of my computer (not sure what's relevant):
Memory: 32 giB
Processor: AMD® Ryzen 7 pro 5850u with radeon graphics × 16
Graphics: AMD® Renoir

`lspci | grep -i net` gives

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0e)  

03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8852AE 802.11ax PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

EDIT: 23-08-2022
The problem seems to have disappeared, or at least significantly reduced in magnitude. My best guess is that it was fixed in an update. If anyone can explain me what could have caused my problem and/or why it might be gone now. I will accept that as an answer.

EDIT: 04-09-2022
Ok I'm sure now it is not a WiFi problem. Whenever I go into the Bluetooth menu (default or Blueman) the computer starts acting very weird. Either all freezes or just the BT menu does. Twice the computer even completely rebooted. The weird thing though is that sometimes everything works completely fine and then suddenly my BT devices keep disconnecting and the menu issues arise.

EDIT: 05-09-2022
When running `sudo dmesg -T --follow` then turning BT off and then on again I get the following output:

```
[Mo Sep  5 16:25:38 2022] hid-generic 0003:25A7:FA61.0007: input,hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Compx 2.4G Receiver] on usb-0000:05:00.3-2/input1
[Mo Sep  5 16:26:51 2022] usb 5-4: USB disconnect, device number 8
[Mo Sep  5 16:26:51 2022] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI reset during shutdown failed
[Mo Sep  5 16:28:20 2022] usb 5-3: reset full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[Mo Sep  5 16:28:20 2022] usb 5-4: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[Mo Sep  5 16:28:21 2022] usb 5-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=4852, bcdDevice= 0.00
[Mo Sep  5 16:28:21 2022] usb 5-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[Mo Sep  5 16:28:21 2022] usb 5-4: Product: Bluetooth Radio
[Mo Sep  5 16:28:21 2022] usb 5-4: Manufacturer: Realtek
[Mo Sep  5 16:28:21 2022] usb 5-4: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
[Mo Sep  5 16:28:21 2022] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0b hci_rev=000a lmp_ver=0b lmp_subver=8852
[Mo Sep  5 16:28:21 2022] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[Mo Sep  5 16:28:21 2022] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8852au_fw.bin
[Mo Sep  5 16:28:21 2022] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8852au_config.bin
[Mo Sep  5 16:28:21 2022] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 6, total sz 44555
[Mo Sep  5 16:28:21 2022] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0xdfb76d7a
[Mo Sep  5 16:28:27 2022] hid-generic 0005:04E8:7021.0008: unknown main item tag 0x0
[Mo Sep  5 16:28:27 2022] input: Bluetooth 5.1 Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.4/usb5/5-4/5-4:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:1/0005:04E8:7021.0008/input/input43
[Mo Sep  5 16:28:27 2022] hid-generic 0005:04E8:7021.0008: input,hidraw3: BLUETOOTH HID v1.1b Keyboard [Bluetooth 5.1 Keyboard] on e0:0a:f6:5d:26:f8
[Mo Sep  5 16:28:28 2022] input: input-remapper Bluetooth 5.1 Keyboard forwarded as /devices/virtual/input/input44
[Mo Sep  5 16:28:48 2022] hid-generic 0005:04E8:7021.0009: unknown main item tag 0x0
[Mo Sep  5 16:28:48 2022] input: Bluetooth 5.1 Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.4/usb5/5-4/5-4:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:2/0005:04E8:7021.0009/input/input45
[Mo Sep  5 16:28:48 2022] hid-generic 0005:04E8:7021.0009: input,hidraw3: BLUETOOTH HID v1.1b Keyboard [Bluetooth 5.1 Keyboard] on e0:0a:f6:5d:26:f8
[Mo Sep  5 16:28:49 2022] input: input-remapper Bluetooth 5.1 Keyboard forwarded as /devices/virtual/input/input46
```

At the same time (when BT is on) CPU usage goes up quite a bit and down again when I turn BT off. This is also correlates heavily with the lagging.

EDIT: 07-09-2022
Whenever some of my BT devices suddenly disconnect I get this output in the terminal (running `sudo dmesg -T --follow`):

```
[Mi Sep  7 20:04:43 2022] usb 5-3: reset full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[Mi Sep  7 20:04:44 2022] usb 5-4: reset full-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
```

Comment: what's most important of all is probably what network card you have.

Comment: Thank you! I edited my question - does this help? Is there more relevant information?

Comment: using dmesg while that issue happens may give some hints on what is causing the issue, maybe a firmware bug, maybe interference of another module or even a hardware problem disconnecting the card for a few milliseconds etc.

Comment: @Amirreza thanks! I added some output. In the worst cases - when my computer reboots - I am not sure how to get the terminal output. But as the lagging happens anyways, maybe that's not strictly necessary. If there is anything else I can include information wise I'd appreciate any instructions.

Comment: These cards are known to be problematic both in Windows and Linux. Some users have had a lot less problems after disabling it's power saving features.

Comment: @svin83 Thanks! Do you mean the Ethernet and Network controllers? Or something else?

Comment: @ArOk Both the Bluetooth and the WiFi hardware is usually combined into one single hardware module in most laptops. Probably an m.2 module.

Comment: @svin83 could you point me towards sources that show me how to disable the power saving features?

Comment: @ArOk It depends on your system configuration.  If you use NetworkManager then this answer may be of help. 
 ```https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/315400/172722```

Comment: try ```sudo add-apt-repository universe && sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade```

Comment: is there any updated on this ? I use 3 bluetooth devices and it was working smoothly, but just out of the blue this problem appear and now when i connect the 3 devices everything goes to sh1#.

Comment: @ArOk, did you find the cause of this problema and how to solve ?

Comment: @Wall-E I tried a few different options sometimes it seemed to work, but never really well. So I ended up going back to Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not all bluetooth chipsets are created equally , when i worked on bluetooth products i used only CSR bluetooth dongles, if you get a random noname one it will probably have these issues.

I have had several laptops where the built in bluetooth just doesn't work properly, sometimes its the antenna , sometimes its just a crap chip , sometimes it needs some wierd windows only setup if its combined with WIFI.

Get an external USB Bluetooth dongle with a CSR chipset, they are about 10 pounds which is cheaper than spending hours chasing unfixable bugs in abandoned hardware.

Just leave it in the usb socket, some are even totally flush.

Comment: the free firmware linux uses for your wifi + Bt card is probably not the same as the commercial one it actually wants but that is stuck inside the windows driver